# Newspaper api for scraping articles

Tags: python-3.x, python-newspaper, newspaper3k

I have used newspaper3k api from python for scraping articles. I am not able to **scrape** Times of India articles , getting publish date null from response rest articles are giving proper articles.

```
article = Article(url)
article.download()
article.parse()
result=vars(article)
print(result['publish_date'])
```

Comment: Can you show the code you've tried, the error messages, and what you expect to happen?

Comment: See all articles are giving  proper date but this Times of  India (TOI) articles domain articles are giving publish date null can TOI articles block some part of response ?

Comment: Sure, the publisher of an API has full control over what is returned, and may choose to implement only part of the spec.

Comment: Can you please share article URL and the response ?

Comment: @Shakeel for example you take this article URL - https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/business/india-business/logistics-it-media-professionals-most-anxious-about-returning-to-work-survey/articleshow/77479303.cms or any TOI articles i will give publish date null  in given object response.

Comment: Yes I they are null values for me as well. Two options either search in TOI forums or have another field as polling date(work around).

Answer (score 0):

The current version of *Newspaper* cannot extract the 'publish date' from the Times of India HTML code, because the date is within a *script* tag.  You can extract this date using *requests* and *BeautifulSoup*. The latter is embedded in *Newspaper*. I also noted that the keywords are in a meta tag, so *Newspaper* cannot extract these. I added some code to extract the keywords too. Hopefully, the code below helps you query articles on the Times of India.  Please let me know if you have any questions.

```
import requests
import re as regex
from newspaper import Article
from newspaper.utils import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/business/india-business/govt-working-to-reduce-e-vehicle-tax-niti-aayog-ceo/articleshow/78210495.cms'

raw_html = requests.get(base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html.text, 'html.parser')

# parse date published
data = soup.findAll('script')[1]
find_date = regex.search(r'datePublished.{3}\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', data.string)
date_published = find_date.group().split('"')[2]

# parse other elements using Newspaper
article = Article('')
article.download(raw_html.content)
article.parse()
article_tags = article.tags
article_content = article.text
article_title = article.title

# parse keywords
article_meta_data = article.meta_data
article_keywords = sorted({value for (key, value) in article_meta_data.items() if key == 'keywords'})
```